# What is the proper notation for a sequence (or function) which starts at zero and has the upper limit of 1 that is never reached?

Tags: notation

If we have a function

f(a, b) = (a-1)/b

where a and b are integers and the values of a range from 1 to b,

what would be the proper way to use notation to describe when the sequence starts and ends? Its lowest value is 0, when a = 1. Its highest value is hypothetically 1, although this is never reached, but you get closer to 1 as you increase b.

Comment: $(a-1)/b$ doesn't depends on $x$, so $f$ is a constant function. Did you meant to write $f(a)$ or $f(a,b)$?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes thanks for noticing it. I guess I wanted to write f(a,b)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$\sup_{\textstyle {1\leqslant a\leqslant b \atop b\in\Bbb N}} f(a,b) = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad f(a,b) < 1$$

or using the domain $f$: $D=\{(a,b)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N \mid 1\leqslant a\leqslant b \}$

$$\sup_{(a,b)\in D} f(a,b) = 1$$

This doesn't however encode the fact that you need $a,b\to\infty$ in order to get arbitrarily close to the supremum. Notice that this condition is only necessary but not sufficient; take for example $b=2a$ so that both $a$ and $b$ tend to infinity but $f(a,b)\to 1/2$.